# How to create a powerapp to receive a push notification

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow which is triggered by a user manually entering an Id. I want to replace the manual trigger with an automated trigger that starts with the receipt of a third party webhook/push notification.
[image]

The third party webhook requires an endpoint/URI to push a payload/notification to. I assume that I need to create a Power App to expose a URI and receive the payload however I have no idea how to do this or if that is even possible.

Every article I find in a Google search tells me how to push a notification from Power Apps but nothing tells me how to receive a notification. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your Power Automate cloud to flow to change the trigger by `When an HTTP request is received`. It's a premium connector, so you need a Power Automate license (per user or per app). You can restrict the method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) and the route (relative path).

After saving the flow, you will get the **endpoint**.

[image: Request trigger]
[image: When an HTTP request is received]
[image: Trigger configuration]